# Cannot Run Project in Eclipse C/C++ OpenCV 2.4.5 Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: eclipse, opencv, ubuntu-12.10

I have just installed OpenCV 2.4.5 and Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers on Ubuntu 12.10 and followed [this opencv.org tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html#linux-eclipse-usage). The project builds with no errors but when I reach the "Running the executable" section from Eclipse, I get the following message after hitting Run:

> /home/pedro/workspace/di/Debug/di: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

EDIT:

Using `sudo dpkg -l | grep opencv` gives:

- ii  libopencv-calib3d2.3                      2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision Camera Calibration library
- ii  libopencv-contrib2.3                      2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision contrib library
- ii  libopencv-core-dev                        2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        development files for libopencv-core
- ii  libopencv-core2.3                         2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision core library
- ii  libopencv-features2d2.3                   2.3.1-11ubuntu2                             amd64        computer vision Feature Detection and Descriptor Extraction library
- ii  libopencv-flann-dev                       2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        development files for libopencv-flann
- ii  libopencv-flann2.3                        2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional spaces library
- ii  libopencv-gpu-dev                         2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        development files for libopencv-gpu
- ii  libopencv-gpu2.3                          2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision GPU Processing library
- ii  libopencv-highgui2.3                      2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision High-level GUI and Media I/O library
- ii  libopencv-imgproc-dev                     2.3.1-11ubuntu2                             amd64        development files for libopencv-imgproc
- ii  libopencv-imgproc2.3                      2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision Image Processing library
- ii  libopencv-legacy2.3                       2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision legacy library
- ii  libopencv-ml-dev                          2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        development files for libopencv-ml
- ii  libopencv-ml2.3                           2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision Machine Learning library
- ii  libopencv-objdetect2.3                    2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision Object Detection library
- ii  libopencv-video-dev                       2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        development files for libopencv-video
- ii  libopencv-video2.3                        2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        computer vision Video analysis library
- ii  opencv-doc                                2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            all          OpenCV documentation and examples
- ii  python-opencv                             2.3.1-11ubuntu2                            amd64        Python bindings for the computer vision library
- rc  ros-fuerte-opencv2                        2.4.2-0precise-20120908-1624-+0000         amd64        OpenCV
- rc  ros-groovy-opencv2                        2.4.4-1quantal-20130325-0857-+0000         amd64        OpenCV

Sorry the formatting is not the best.

The command "locate libopencv_core"

- /usr/lib/libopencv_core.a
- /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so
- /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3
- /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2

"locate libopencv" shows a extensive list that I don't know if it would be appropriate to copy it.

Comment: That's interesting. What is the output when you say `"locate libopencv"` or `"locate libopencv_core"` in command prompt? Is there any such file there but with other version? Did you install some packages manually, or all from repository? (Were there `ldconfig` issued?)

Comment: "locate libopencv_core" gives the following: /usr/lib/libopencv_core.a
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1 

I installed all of them from repository following tutorials and using ldconfig in one of the steps.

Comment: You say it returns nothing? What does `"locate libopencv"` return and now most importantly, what does `sudo dpkg -l | grep opencv` shows?

Comment: How experienced are you with Ubuntu / Linux? I assumed that if you could build it you have the required knowledge. If you could build it, you must have the required *-dev packages installed, and I thought those should automatically pull-in the library packages themselves (they depend on them). What was your installation procedure?

Comment: The tutorial what you linked pulls a source of OpenCV from GitHub and compiles it. If you installed opencv from Ubuntu 12.10 repo, that is usually little behind than the most recent source version.

Comment: I am new linux user. In order to install opencv I followed these tutorials: http://www.linuxhispano.net/2012/11/05/instalar-opencv-2-4-2-ubuntu-12-04/  http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation-2-3-1/  http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation. I will edit the post with the results from the commands you've asked.

Comment: I think you compiled the 2.3.1 version following the ozbotz tutorial? Compile the 2.4.5 version and probably you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu Quency Quantal 12.10 has 2.3.1 packages in it's repo:
[OpenCV in Ubuntu 12.10 repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=opencv&searchon=names&suite=quantal&section=all)
The next version, raring has 2.4.
I'd uninstall Ubuntu 12.10's various v2.3.1 opencv related packages. (How did they got installed? Did you install them manually, or something pulled them in?). Then I'd try to compile+install the OpenCV source again. The install stage of the make procedure should provide libraries to you.

Comment: I actually was careful to compile the 2.4.5 instead of 2.3.1.

Comment: Hmmm. In the dpkg package list it seems that most of your related packages have version 2.3.1. Then you need to fix that.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer, so the problem will be that 12.10 has v2.3.1 OpenCV in it's repos. I'll look into the tutorials how they can resolve that.

Comment: After editing the "opencv.config" file from "/usr/local/lib" to "/usr/local/lib/" and then run "sudo ldconfig -v", I was able to run the program without errors. I guess there was a problem when I first ran ldconfig and I didn't notice.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. My answer is kind of off though then. But I'd be still a little bit concerned about the 2.3.1 version packages you have in your system from the 12.10 repo. They can cause trouble later.